# Detect Tab control selection changed by user

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF. I have one project which have one tab control consists of 2 tabs. To default selection the first tab item have the property '*IsSelected=True*'.

This working fine. But i need to capture the user changed events which means if the user changed the selection, i need to capture that change with value. For this i created one event arguments by implementing '*FrameworkElementHandlerEventArgs*'

My existing code like below;

```
public class SelectionChanagedEventArgs : FrameworkElementHandlerEventArgs
    {
        public object SelectedItem { get; set; }
    }
```

I am registering this event to capture the changes

```
RegisterEvent<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(
                (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    //Here i got the selection changes
                },
handler,handler);
```

This is my code part only.

This is working fine. The issue is the default selection. When the application launches, it fires the default selection and got the changes in the event. But i need to capture only the user changed event. Any option to check  or detect the changes done by user only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added IsLoaded property to verify whether the control is loaded for presentation. Now working fine. Please share if you think any another issue impact due to this.

The following is my update code:

```
RegisterEvent<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(
                (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e == null || !(sender as System.Windows.Controls.Control).IsLoaded)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    //Here i got the selection changes
                },
handler,handler);
```

Comment: Are you planning to upvote any of the other answers which suggested more or less the same thing?

Comment: You may also try to check the IsLoaded property of the view itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `IsSelected` property of the first `TabItem` programmatically in your code *before* you hook up the event handler.

Or you could use a variable that keeps track of the number of times your event handler has been invoked and then simply return immediately the first time:

```
int count;
RegisterEvent<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(
(sender, e) =>
{
    if (e == null || count++ == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    //Here i got the selection changes
}, handler, handler);
```

Or check if the view has been loaded:

```
if (e == null || !IsLoaded)
```

There is no specific "user changed event". It is the exact same event that gets fired regardless of whether the user actually made an active selection or not.

Comment: For grammatically will try and update. For second, count is fine. But there number of controls not only one tab control. so simple one count will fire event from second controls.

Comment: Set the IsSelected property after you have hooked up the event handler then.

Comment: yes. I need to update the tab selection when the page shown. The event is fired whenever the selection change happened

Comment: Did you even read my answer/comment? The event handler won't be invoked before you have attached it. Do this before you select any item. What's the problem with this?

Comment: i got you. But I am beginner to this wpf. So my understanding is we just removed IsSelected property from xaml and bind this as  property in the OnEnter method? sorry if i wrong

Comment: Remove it from the XAML and set it before you are calling the RegisterEvent method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148881/discussion-between-akhil-and-mm8).

Answer (score 0):

You might try to check if there was a previous selection:

```
        tab.SelectionChanged += (sender, e) => {
            if (e.RemovedItems.Count == 0)
                return;

            //Here i got the selection changes
        };
```

where `tab` is your `TabControl`. You don't need to create your custom class with event arguments.

Comment: what is this 'e.RemovedItems.Count' property? any logic to be added in my custom event args

Comment: @Akhil It is the list of unselected items, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.removeditems(v=vs.110).aspx). And since the `TabControl` has no selection when created, you can perform this simple check to achieve desired functionality.

Comment: hi thanks but i used custom args not windows Selection Changed. I use custom class inherited from FrameworkElementHandlerEventArgs. ok so how i get the selected item

Comment: @Akhil is that neccessary?

Comment: sorry because i used the methods for logging and events all are from one custom library created by another team. They used this args